# border-image not showing in HTML Email

Tags: html, gmail, border-image

So I have a div with a border. However, the border image is not showing up. It displays it as an ordinary solid border. It's weird, the URL is valid and working, it is from google drive, everything looks good. The HTML itself works, but when I use it in an email it doesn't.

```html
<div style="-webkit-border-image: url(https://s32.postimg.org/rfht7aqx1/border.png) 46px round;-o-border-image: url(https://s32.postimg.org/rfht7aqx1/border.png) 46px round;border-image: url(https://s32.postimg.org/rfht7aqx1/border.png) 46 round;border-width: 46px;border-style: solid;">Hello world!!!</div>
```

It's really weird; I've never seen anything like this. I'm sending to Gmail BTW and am not sure if it works with [Outlook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook) or something else.

**PS:** I know the border looks a little weird; that's because its height is small. I am aware of that, so don't complain about it.

Comment: Unfortunately most email clients do not support these kind of things, Gmail being one of them. As far as I know there is no real effective alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there's no way, Gmail does not support `border-image` property.

check here for tag compatibility:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Damn it. So is there any services I could use that would make it work?

Comment: Or can you link me to a tutorial on making the border out of a table?

Comment: If you have a simple border, you can use borders on a `<td>` element:
`<td style="border: solid 1px #e9e9e9;>[your content]</td>`
and put your content into this element.


Otherwise, you can slice your border image and reproduce it using tables
http://blog.bronto.com/commercemarketing/how-to-build-an-email-using-sliced-images-without-embarrassing-yourself-or-getting-fired/ 
(like a mosaic, with your content on center)

Answer (score 2):

Since `border-image` is not supported by most Email vendors, You can just simulate a `border-image` using the `background-image` (since that one is supported by Gmail) property in combination with a `div` or any other element you feel like using. You will have to modify the `padding` property a bit if you are using it on your div. But this is how i did it and it looks just like a `border-image`.

Here is how mine looks:

[image: simulating border-image with a backrounded div]